# Directory VS Package in flutter project using Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am a new flutter developer I use android in my practicing when I was using an old version I was able to create dart packages from menu add package
Now I just found a directory instead of packages does it the same? If not, how can I find a way from the menu to create a dart package in flutter

I didn't try this version before